# Substituição válida da produção para LL(1)

Tags: compiladores

Tenho a seguinte produção: **S → if E then S else S fi | if E then S fi | K**

Considerando **ε** como a sentença vazia, qual seria uma substituição válida para obter uma gramática equivalente que seja LL(1)?

Comment: Você pode especificar mais qual é a dúvida que você tem? O que você já tentou fazer? Porque você precisa de uma gramática LL(1)?

Comment: A gramática cima tem que ser convertida pra LL(1). Tentei usar métodos para fazer as substituições válidas. Preciso destes métodos porque a produção gera uma interseção entre First(αβ) e First(αδ) (dois "First"), que não é válido pra LL(1).

Comment: Parece que achei a resposta:

[quebralinha]S → if E then S R fi | K [quebralinha]
R → else S | ε